# Login loop after installing Ubuntu 16.04 server and adding Ubuntu desktop and MATE desktop

Tags: login, login-screen

I have created a new Ubuntu 16.04 server installation today, added Ubuntu-desktop and mate-desktop, and now whenever I try to log in with the user I created during setup, the login screen comes back and no error message is displayed. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and there my login works fine.

I do `ls` and I have only `Desktop` directory.

So I saw some answers recommending deleting `.Xauthority`, which I did, but it did not help

I rebooted and tried MATE desktop. When I try to login, I get an error:

```
Could not update ICEAuthority file /home/myuser/iceauthority
```

and

```
Path for the directory containing caja settings need read and write permissions /home/myuser/.config/caja
```

I ran

```
chmod 777 .config
```

which enabled me to log in, but I can't see any menu or link or icon except a link to my home directory, so the system is unusable.

So what is going wrong?

[image: .ICEauthority owned by salam (user) with rw-r--r--]

Here is the ouput for tail xsession:

[image: xsession-errors]

Comment: I forgot to mention that after this 1st error message, I get a 2nd one indicating " Path for the directory containing caja settings need read and  write permissions /home/myuser/.config/caja".

Comment: Please log in via Ctrl+Alt+F1 again and run `namei -l ~/.ICEauthority` (note the capitalization) and [edit] your question to include the result

Comment: HI, any feedback?

Comment: Can you describe the link that you see in more detail? Is there anything of interest in the `.xsession-errors` file? (you can add the output of `tail ~/.xsession-errors` to your question)

Comment: I responded and added a snapshot in my initial post

Comment: I still don't see a description of the "link to my home directory" anywhere - my best guess is that your problem is a result of file *ownership* rather than permissions: you could run `find ~ ! \( -uid $(id -u) -gid $(id -g) \) -ls` to see what non user-owned files / directories exist in your home dir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)